# Equivalent of RelativeLayout in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-relativelayout

Is there a way to implement something similar to what `RelativeLayout` does on Android?

In particular I'm looking for something similar to `centerInParent`, `layout_below:<layout_id>`, `layout_above:<layout_id>`, and `alignParentLeft`

For more reference on RelativeLayout: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

EDIT: here is an example of a layout relying on `RelativeLayout`

[image: Screenshot]

So in the image above, on top, the "tofu's Songs" text is aligned as `centerInParent` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Whereas the other 2 are `alignParentLeft` and `alignParentRight`

On each cell, where the fire icon is at, the number of likes on the bottom of it is aligned around the center of the flame icon. Also, the top and bottom title on each cell are aligned to the right and to the top and bottom of the image avatar, respectively.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Flutter layouts are usually built using a tree of [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), [`Row`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widgets. These widgets take constructor arguments that specify rules for how the children are laid out relative to the parent, and you can also influence layout of individual children by wrapping them in [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), [`Flexible`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html), [`Positioned`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html), [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html), or [`Center`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html) widgets.

It is also possible to build complex layouts using [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html). This is how [`Scaffold`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) is implemented internally, and an example of how to use it in an app appears in the [Shrine demo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/shrine/shrine_home.dart). You can also use [`LayoutBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) or [`CustomPaint`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html), or go down a layer and extend [`RenderObject`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) as shown in the [sector example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/rendering/src/sector_layout.dart). Doing your layouts manually like this is more work and creates more potential for errors in corner cases, so I would try to get by with the high-level layout primitives if you can.

To answer your specific questions:

- Use the `leading` and `trailing` arguments to [`AppBar`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) to position your app bar elements. If you want to use a `Row` instead, use a `mainAxisAlignment` of `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.
- Use a [`Row`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) with a `crossAxisAlignment` of `CrossAxisAlignment.center` to position the fire icon and number underneath.
- Use a [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) with a `mainAxisAlignment` of `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to position your top and bottom title. (You should consider using [`ListTile`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) to lay out the list tiles, but you'll lose control over the exact positioning if you do this.)

Here is a code snippet that implements the design you provided. In this example I used an [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) to determine the height of the song tiles, but you can improve the performance by hard coding them to a fixed height.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: new HomeScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class Song extends StatelessWidget {
  const Song({ this.title, this.author, this.likes });

  final String title;
  final String author;
  final int likes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme textTheme = Theme
      .of(context)
      .textTheme;
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.3),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      child: new IntrinsicHeight(
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 10.0),
              child: new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(
                  'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src'
                    '&size=small&type=jpg#${title.hashCode}'
                ),
                radius: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Container(
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(title, style: textTheme.subhead),
                    new Text(author, style: textTheme.caption),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              child: new InkWell(
                child: new Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 40.0),
                onTap: () {
                  // TODO(implement)
                },
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              child: new InkWell(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 25.0),
                    new Text('${likes ?? ''}'),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  // TODO(implement)
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Feed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView(
      children: [
        new Song(title: 'Trapadelic lobo', author: 'lillobobeats', likes: 4),
        new Song(title: 'Different', author: 'younglowkey', likes: 23),
        new Song(title: 'Future', author: 'younglowkey', likes: 2),
        new Song(title: 'ASAP', author: 'tha_producer808', likes: 13),
        new Song(title: '', author: 'TraphousePeyton'),
        new Song(title: 'Something sweet...', author: '6ryan'),
        new Song(title: 'Sharpie', author: 'Fergie_6'),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomTabBar extends AnimatedWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  CustomTabBar({ this.pageController, this.pageNames })
    : super(listenable: pageController);

  final PageController pageController;
  final List<String> pageNames;

  @override
  final Size preferredSize = new Size(0.0, 40.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme textTheme = Theme
      .of(context)
      .textTheme;
    return new Container(
      height: 40.0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey.shade800.withOpacity(0.5),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: new List.generate(pageNames.length, (int index) {
          return new InkWell(
            child: new Text(
              pageNames[index],
              style: textTheme.subhead.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(
                  index == pageController.page ? 1.0 : 0.2,
                ),
              )
            ),
            onTap: () {
              pageController.animateToPage(
                index,
                curve: Curves.easeOut,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              );
            }
          );
        })
          .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  PageController _pageController = new PageController(initialPage: 2);

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    final Map<String, Widget> pages = <String, Widget>{
      'My Music': new Center(
        child: new Text('My Music not implemented'),
      ),
      'Shared': new Center(
        child: new Text('Shared not implemented'),
      ),
      'Feed': new Feed(),
    };
    TextTheme textTheme = Theme
      .of(context)
      .textTheme;
    return new Stack(
      children: [
        new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(
              begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
              end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                const Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 72, 72),
                const Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 97, 249),
              ],
              stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            )
          ),
          child: new Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            child: new Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: new Text(
                'T I Z E',
                style: textTheme.headline.copyWith(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade800.withOpacity(0.8),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )
          )
        ),
        new Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0x00000000),
          appBar: new AppBar(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0x00000000),
            elevation: 0.0,
            leading: new Center(
              child: new ClipOval(
                child: new Image.network(
                  'http://i.imgur.com/TtNPTe0.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  // TODO: implement
                },
              ),
            ],
            title: const Text('tofu\'s songs'),
            bottom: new CustomTabBar(
              pageController: _pageController,
              pageNames: pages.keys.toList(),
            ),
          ),
          body: new PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            children: pages.values.toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Final note: In this example, I used a regular `AppBar`, but you could also use a `CustomScrollView` with a pinned `SliverAppBar` that has an `elevation` of 0.0. That would make the content visible as it scrolls behind your app bar. It is tricky to get this to play nicely with `PageView`, because it's expecting a fixed size area to lay itself out into.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend omitting IntrinsicHeight as font size can be changed by the user and the layout can easily break.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `Stack` and can have its children as `Positioned` or `Align`.

***Example #1*** (Using `Positioned` in `Stack`)

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(left: 0.0, child: Text("Top\nleft")),
    Positioned(bottom: 0.0, child: Text("Bottom\nleft")),
    Positioned(top: 0.0, right: 0.0, child: Text("Top\nright")),
    Positioned(bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0, child: Text("Bottom\nright")),
    Positioned(bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0, child: Text("Bottom\nright")),
    Positioned(left: width / 2, top: height / 2, child: Text("Center")),
    Positioned(top: height / 2, child: Text("Center\nleft")),
    Positioned(top: height / 2, right: 0.0, child: Text("Center\nright")),
    Positioned(left: width / 2, child: Text("Center\ntop")),
    Positioned(left: width / 2, bottom: 0.0, child: Text("Center\nbottom")),
  ],
)
```

***Example #2*** (Using `Align` in `Stack`)

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("Center"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight, child: Text("Top\nRight"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text("Center\nRight"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, child: Text("Bottom\nRight"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft, child: Text("Top\nLeft"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text("Center\nLeft"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, child: Text("Bottom\nLeft"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child: Text("Top\nCenter"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: Text("Bottom\nCenter"),),
    Align(alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.5), child: Text("Custom\nPostition", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),),),
  ],
);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Really helpful, I think what most developers coming from Android are looking for is a layout like Constraint Layout. Is there anything like that in flutter?

Comment: @user3833732 You can pretty much achieve anything using Flutter inbuilt widget. If you have any layout and you think you are not able to implement it using Flutter, post it as a question, and message me, I will try to answer it.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but can someone explain where "width" and "height" come from?  How do you know the size of the parent?

Comment: @JunInoue Use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/height`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example to show how `Stack` along with `Positioned` can be used to make it work like `RelativeLayout`.

[image]

```
double _containerHeight = 120, _imageHeight = 80, _iconTop = 44, _iconLeft = 12, _marginLeft = 110;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          height: _containerHeight,
          child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: _iconLeft,
          top: _iconTop,
          child: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        Positioned(
          right: _iconLeft,
          top: _iconTop,
          child: Icon(Icons.bubble_chart, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: _iconLeft,
          top: _containerHeight - _imageHeight / 2,
          child: ClipOval(child: Image.asset("assets/images/profile.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover, height: _imageHeight, width: _imageHeight)),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: _marginLeft,
          top: _containerHeight - (_imageHeight / 2.5),
          child: Text("CopsOnRoad", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18)),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          left: _marginLeft,
          top: _containerHeight + (_imageHeight / 4),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("2", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text("Gold", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("22", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text("Silver", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("28", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text("Bronze", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                ],
              ),
              Container(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Android's `RelativeLayout` (and in fact more powerful) is the `AlignPositioned` widget from the `align_positioned` package:

https://pub.dev/packages/align_positioned

From its docs:

> When your desired layout feels too complex for Columns and Rows,
> AlignPositioned is a real life saver. Flutter is very composable,
> which is good, but sometimes it's unnecessarily complex to translate
> some layout requirement into a composition of simpler widgets.
>
> The AlignPositioned aligns, positions, sizes, rotates and transforms
> its child in relation to both the container and the child itself. In
> other words, it lets you easily and directly define where and how a
> widget should appear in relation to another.
>
> For example, you can tell it to position the top-left of its child at
> 15 pixels to the left of the top-left corner of the container, plus
> move it two thirds of the child's height to the bottom plus 10 pixels,
> and then rotate 15 degrees. Do you even know how to start doing this
> by composing basic Flutter widgets? Maybe, but with AlignPositioned
> it's much easier, and it takes a single widget.

However, the specific example in the question is quite simple, I'd just use `Row`s, `Column`s etc anyway. *Note: I am the author of this package.*